# Joomla 3 Cache Clear Issue

Tags: php, caching, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

When I makes any change to any part of Joomla components or modules, it doesn't affects directly to my website.

Every time I have to Delete all Cache from Tools->Clear Cache to see effect of my newly updated components or modules or any part of my website. Is there any way automatically Cache Clearing in Joomla

Answer (score 1):

There are two cache cleaner extensions in Joomla that can do the job

1. manually with one click.
   http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/cache-cleaner
2. do the job automatically. 
   http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/quick-cache-cleaning
   here on any preset event the cache gets cleared automatically. Enable the plugin once you upload it.

Comment: I Installed Second One. but cache is not Clear Automatically.

Comment: @Karthikmathesh Did you enable the plugin and adjusted the parameters in the plugin as per your requirement.

Comment: @Karthikmathesh Also under settings  Article Save Process chose option yes.